# How to exclude a table with a specific ID?

Tags: jquery

I need help in jQuery.
I need to add in my `if` statement the condition that the table must **not** have the `id` 'pippo'.

My `if` statement is the following:

```
if (
  HtmlPath.indexOf('ZOSHTML/DTREND') > -1 || 
  HtlPath.indexOf('LNXHTML/DTREND/LDRSYS.') > -1 || 
  HtmlPath.indexOf('LNXHTML/DTREND/LDMAIN.') > -1 &&
  // put here the condition that the table must not contain the ID pippo
) {
  $("table.NAVREP").epvMinMax();
}
```

Comment: try adding `table:not(#pippo)`

Comment: can't you use if($('table').attr('id') != 'pippo'){//do something}

Comment: I use if ( HtmlPath.indexOf('ZOSHTML/DTREND')>-1 ||  (HtmlPath.indexOf('LNXHTML/DTREND/LDRSYS.')>-1 || HtmlPath.indexOf('LNXHTML/DTREND/LDMAIN.')>-1 && $('table').attr('id') != '_TBL6_LDSYPCT')) { but it doesn't work i don't undestand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the jQuery [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to check that the `id` attribute is not 'pippo':

```
if (
  HtmlPath.indexOf('ZOSHTML/DTREND') > -1 ||
  HtmlPath.indexOf('LNXHTML/DTREND/LDRSYS.') > -1 ||
  HtmlPath.indexOf('LNXHTML/DTREND/LDMAIN.') > -1 &&
  $('table').attr('id') != 'pippo'
) {
  $('table.NAVREP').epvMinMax();
}
```

Comment: it was ok, i had an error in my syntax thanks a lot